# Dynamic $and query not working mongodb

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

```
$SearchParam = $_GET["tag"];
$strcount = substr_count($SearchParam, ' ');
// Code to get the tag strings and create the search parm accordingly
if ($strcount > 0)
{
$fruitQuery = "'$" ."and' => array(";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $strcount; $i++)
{
    $strfind = strpos($SearchParam,' ');
    $fruitQuery = $fruitQuery . "array('ta' => " . "'" .substr($SearchParam,0,$strfind) . "'),";
    $SearchParam = substr($SearchParam,$strfind+1,strlen($fruitQuery));
    if ($i == $strcount)
    {
        $fruitQuery = $fruitQuery . "array('ta' => " . "'" . $SearchParam . "'))";
    }
}
}
else
{
$fruitQuery = array('ta' => $SearchParam);
}
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB('wikisrch');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'dailymotion');
//$cursor = $collection->find($fruitQuery)->limit(12);
$cursor = $collection->find(array($fruitQuery));
var_dump($db->lastError());
```

This is my code and I'm creating a dynamic query to mongodb Database based on the search parameter. While creating a dynamic query it is returning it as error .

This is the string getting generated in $fruitQuery. Where input is 'camera lifestyle'
'$and' => array(array('ta' => 'camera'),array('ta' => 'lifestyle'))

This is the last error message.
    array(4) { ["n"]=> int(0) ["connectionId"]=> int(1) ["err"]=> NULL ["ok"]=> float(1) }

When I looked in to Mongod console it is showing the below message.
$err :"invalid operator :$and , code 10068.

Could you please help me solving this issue.

Comment: Can you give the sql syntax of the query?

Comment: Sql? You made my day!

Comment: The expected sql query is select * from db.dailymotion where ta= 'camera' and ta = 'lifestyle' fetch first 10 rows only ;

Answer (score 0):

This is due to error in javascript code:

$fruitQuery = "'$" ."and' => array("; It is throwing an error : "missing name after . operator".

Let me know if this resolves the issue.

Comment: No I concatenating the query below and it is coming as below at the end.    '$and' => array(array('ta' => 'camera'),array('ta' => 'lifestyle')) I believe this should be a problem. Error is also that $and is not getting recognized